# android listview button control

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have an android listview filled with items.

Every item has a button.

This is the template of the my listview.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:paddingTop="5px"
        android:paddingRight="5px"
        android:gravity="left">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView_test1"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:paddingLeft="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView_test2"
            android:layout_width="250dip"
            android:paddingLeft="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView_test3"
            android:layout_width="400dip"
            android:paddingLeft="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_buttontest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Button_buttontest"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How could i handle the click of each button in the activity code? 
Each button has the same id "Button_buttontest"?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards.
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to create a custom `Adapter` that connects a `View.OnClickListener` to the button when the view for the row is created.  Since you're creating the OnClickListener from within the view, you'll know the position of the row that was clicked.  There might be a better way, but this is the first thing that comes to mind.